# How to convert two concatenate string vars to %m%Y format

Tags: r, date, as.date

I created a character variable called `long.oto.yeni$Date`. Now I need to transform this variable to `%m/%Y` format to plot time series graph in `ggplot2`. So I am unable to use `yearmon()` function from `zoo` package.

But when I used `as.Date()` function, output has created `NA` values. How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks.

```
long.oto.yeni$Date <- paste0(long.oto.yeni$Month, "/", long.oto.yeni$Year)
long.oto.yeni$Date <- as.Date(long.oto.yeni$Date, "%m/%Y")
```

Comment: *"transform this variable to %m/%Y format"*, do you mean transform to a `POSIXct` or `Date` class? No class in R references `Month`, they all refer to a date or time. Because of this, you need to provide a *day* as well. (I think Tim's anwer is likely going to help you, though without sample data it is rather difficult to provide specific help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `"yearmon"` class to avoid having to deal with the day of the month.  Read `long.oto.yeni` into a zoo object `oto` converting its index to class `"yearmon"`.  Then plot with `autoplot.zoo`.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

long.oto.yeni <- data.frame(Month = 1:5, Year = 2000, y = (1:5)^2) # input

to_yearmon <- function(y, m) as.yearmon(paste(y, m, sep = "-"))
oto <- read.zoo(long.oto.yeni, index = c("Year", "Month"), FUN = to_yearmon)

autoplot(oto) + scale_x_yearmon() + xlab("")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You need a day component in addition to month and year to form a date using `as.Date`.  Arbitrarily, you could choose the first of the month for each date:

```
long.oto.yeni$Date <- as.Date(paste0("01-",
                              long.oto.yeni$Month, "-",
                              long.oto.yeni$Year), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Good answer stressing that we generally want the `Date` type, but you use `-` in  the paste and `/` in the format which may need a cleanup.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Not _may_, definitely was a typo.  Always helps to test one's code, but then again can't always test everything here.

Comment: Just use the anydate() function from my anytime package :)

Answer (score 1):

A small comment for the sake of completeness: you may use `zoo` package as well, but you need then a combination of `as.yearmon()` and `as.Date()` like this

```
long.oto.yeni$Date <- paste0(long.oto.yeni$Month, "/", long.oto.yeni$Year)
long.oto.yeni$Date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(long.oto.yeni$Date, "%m/%Y"))
```

Another solution proposed by @Dirk Eddelbuettel is to use `anytime` package:

```
library("anytime")
long.oto.yeni$Date <- anydate(paste0(long.oto.yeni$Year, "-", long.oto.yeni$Month))
```

Note please that in both approaches you will obtain the first day of the month, which means that the result will be the same as in the answer of @Tim Biegeleisen